# How to make only the centre of an image -animation png- clickable?

Tags: html, css

I have the following like button implemented as follows:

```js
const $heart = document.getElementById('heart')
$heart.addEventListener('click', event => {
  $heart.classList.toggle('liked')
})
```

```css
body {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      margin: 0;
      height: 100vh;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
    }

.like {
  cursor: pointer;
    border: solid red 2px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/uMu1sxc.png');
  background-size: 1450px 50px;
}

.liked {
  animation-name: like;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: steps(28);
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes like {
  100% {
    background-position-x: right;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Twitter Like</h1>
<div class="tweet-box">
    <div class="like" id="heart"></div>
```

The problem is that the heart is clickable from anywhere inside the red box. I'm hoping that only the center of the red box/the heart shape is clickable

I have been testing solutions for centering images to be clickable but it doesn't seem to help. I'm wondering what's the difference in this scenario. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution would be to add a new element that will trigger the animation on click. That element will have the heart's size and positioned in the middle:

```js
const $clickArea = document.getElementById('click-area')
$clickArea.addEventListener('click', event => {
  document.getElementById('heart').classList.toggle('liked');
})
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
}
    
.tweet-box {
  position: relative;
}

#click-area {
  position: absolute;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  left: calc(50% - 8px);
  top: calc(50% - 8px);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.like {
  border: solid red 2px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/uMu1sxc.png');
  background-size: 1450px 50px;
}

.liked {
  animation-name: like;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: steps(28);
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes like {
  100% {
    background-position-x: right;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Twitter Like</h1>
<div class="tweet-box">
  <div id="click-area"></div>
  <div class="like" id="heart"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const $heart = document.getElementById('heart')
$heart.addEventListener('click', event => {
  $heart.classList.toggle('liked')
})
```

```css
body {
          display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
          margin: 0;
          height: 100vh;
          font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
        }
    
    .tweet-box{
      border: solid red 2px;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      
    }
    .like {
      cursor: pointer;
      width: 35px;
      height: 35px;
      background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/uMu1sxc.png');
      background-size: 1450px 50px;
    }
    
    .liked {
      animation-name: like;
      animation-duration: 1s;
      animation-timing-function: steps(28);
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
    
    @keyframes like {
      100% {
        background-position-x: right;
      }
    }
```

```html
<h1>Twitter Like</h1>
<div class="tweet-box">
    <div class="like" id="heart"></div>
  </div>
```

You added width and height at hearth , you need to add width and height 50px 
    on

Comment: How do i center the box `tweet-box` in the middle?

Answer (score 0):

My method is to add an image layer and use image map for a clickable circle area.

Here is the codepen [link](https://codepen.io/yinsweet/pen/rNOQPaX).

```js
function toggleLiked() {
  const $heart = document.getElementById('heart');
  $heart.classList.toggle('liked');
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
}

.tweet-box {
  position: relative;
}

#imglayer {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 25px);
  left: calc(50% - 25px);
  opacity: 0;
  filter: Alpha(opacity=0);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

#imgmap {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.like {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: solid red 2px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/uMu1sxc.png');
  background-size: 1450px 50px;
}

.liked {
  animation-name: like;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: steps(28);
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes like {
  100% {
    background-position-x: right;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Twitter Like</h1>
<div class="tweet-box">
  <div class="like" id="heart"></div>
  <img id="imglayer" usemap="#workmap" src="https://picsum.photos/50">
</div>
<map id="imgmap" name="workmap">
  <area shape="circle" coords="25, 25, 9" onclick="toggleLiked()">
</map>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have reduced the `width` and `height` of like box and added `margin` to be in the center. Also added `background-position` to bring image in center of like box and reduced the `animation-timing-function` steps for it to adjust the new dimensions.

Hope it helps.

```js
const $heart = document.getElementById('heart')
$heart.addEventListener('click', event => {
  $heart.classList.toggle('liked')
})
```

```css
body {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      margin: 0;
      height: 100vh;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
    }
    
.tweet-box{
    border: solid red 2px;
}

.like {
  cursor: pointer;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    margin: 12.5px;
    background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/uMu1sxc.png);
    background-size: 1450px 50px;
    background-position-x: -12.5px;
    background-position-y: center;
}

.liked {
  animation-name: like;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: steps(14);
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes like {
  100% {
    background-position-x: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Twitter Like</h1>
<div class="tweet-box">
    <div class="like" id="heart"></div>
</div>
```